# Fetching Multiple rows and Store it to another table in php Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a program to take student attendance data and store it in the database.I have created student_table which stores student details after registration, such as Names, Passport no, Class. I have created another table "attendance_table". I have fetched the student details on a php file and displayed with additional column "attendance" which takes radio button values to mark either present or absent.

My problem is after marking the attendance I want it get stored in attendance_table. Since the details are fetched from student_table, how can I able to store it in another table. I'm new to php. Thanks.

```
// FETCHING DATA FROM STUDENT_TABLE//

  <tr>
<td><?php echo $row['student_name']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['Passport_no'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['Teacher'] ?></td>

<td><?php echo $row['Class'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['Period'] ?></td>

<td>
Present<input required type="radio" name="attendance[<?php echo $row['stud_id'] ?>]" value="Present" checked>
Absent<input required type="radio" name="attendance[<?php echo $row['stud_id']; ?>]" value="Absent" >
</td>

</tr>
  <?php } ?>
```

//ATTENDANCE TABLE//

Table structure for table `attendance`

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `attendance`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `attendance` (
  `at_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `stud_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`student_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Passport_no` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Class` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Period` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Status` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Date` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`at_id`)
)
```

Comment: After submitting the form, you will get the submitted data. if you do not know how to work with those data, you can ask here.

Comment: Hi Mawia. I checked up your profile but unfortunately I couldn't  find where to ask questions. Could you help me with my problem? Thanks.

Comment: I did write the code for you. please check.

Answer (score 0):

Dirie what you need to do is put the data in each row into a form https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp.  When a radio button is selected trigger a submit with jquery/javscript. Alternatively have a button/input(submit) called "Present" that will submit the form for you.

Another option is to use ajax (https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_php.asp). I personally think submitting the form is easier though.

I suspect that you are expecting the answer to provide code for you, but I am not sure whether you will get someone who will write out a solution for you. 
There is a lot of code examples online on how to create a HTML form, submit data and save the details from the Form into a database. 
Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Creating form in html is easy enough. Just put the data you want to submit in the form elements. In this example, `period` is put in the `input tag` with hidden attribute and we assign the value from your query.

```
<form method="POST" action="saveattendance.php">
<table>     
        <?php while($row = $db->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)): ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="period" value="<?php echo $row['Period'] ?>">
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['student_name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Passport_no'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Teacher'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Class'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Period'] ?></td>
            <td>Present<input required type="radio" name="attendance[<?php echo $row['stud_id'] ?>]" value="Present" checked>
                Absent<input required type="radio" name="attendance[<?php echo $row['stud_id']; ?>]" value="Absent">
            </td>
        </tr>
          <?php endwhile; ?> 
        <tr>
            <td colspan="6"><input type="submit" name="attendanceData" value="Save"></td>
        </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

In order to save the form to the database, we would need a database connection, here I used PDO mysql.

saveattendance.php

```
<?php 
require_once 'dbconnect.php';//contains PDO connection script

if(isset($_POST['attendanceData'])){
    $today = date('Y-m-d');
    $period = $_POST['period'];
    foreach($_POST['attendance'] as $key =>$val){       
        $studentid = $key;
        $status = $val;

        if(!empty($studentid)){
            try{
                $dbh->beginTransaction();
                $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `attendance` (`stud_id`,`Period`, `Status`,`Date`)VALUES(?,?,?,?)");
                $stmt->execute(array($studentid, $period, $status, $today));
                $update = $stmt->rowCount();
                $dbh->commit();
            }catch(PDOException $e){
                $dbh->rollBack();
                $error = $e->getMessage();//Print the error
                exit;
            }
        }else{
            //Student ID not there
        }
    }

}else{
    //Form not submitted, display other useful info
}
?>
```